# How to print Last Executed Query on controller in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have created following method to verify admin in 
AdminModel.php

```
public function verifyAdmin($where){
    $admin = AdminModel::where($where)->get();
    if($admin->isEmpty()){
        $emptyArray=array();
        return $emptyArray;
    }else{
        return $admin;
    }       
  }
```

Now this model's method is used in controller as follows AdminController.php

```
public function adminLogin(AdminLoginRequest $request)
{       
    $adminModel = new AdminModel();
    $email=$request->email;
    $password=$request->password;
    $where=array('email'=>$email,'password'=>md5($password));
    $getUser=$adminModel->verifyAdmin($where);

     if(!empty($getUser)){          
        session()->put('email',$email);
        return redirect('admin-dashboard');
     }else{
        return redirect('admin')->with('error', 'Invalid email or password !');
     }
}
```

Now I want to echo last executed query in the controller after the models method call .

How can I do this please suggest me, I am using Laravel 5.4